# Android: Content rolling over tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am writing an app for android that requires tabs and I have the content from my list rolling over my tabs.  I know it must be something simple, but I cannot find it.

Here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TabWidget android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@android:id/tabs" />

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">

    </FrameLayout>

</TabHost>
```

and here is the java code

```
public class Again extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Download.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("download")
                .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ok))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Settings.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("settings")
                .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ok))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jason

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling setContentView on a tabactivity? You shouldn't generally do that. It's almost certainly because your framelayout is set to fill_parent. You don't need a view for a tabactivity, it has it all internally.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking but i just figured it out.  For anyone that was as dumb as me, if the main.xml isnt set up right then the content doesnt know where to go.  I hate to be so vague, but i kept messing with it until it worked and cant give you a better answer than that.  Here is the new main.xml if you want to look at it.

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+layout/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

good luck coding guys.

later